# Using multiple javascript files

Tags: javascript, object

I have a very large number of objects that I want to declare.  However, I'd like to do so in an auxiliary javascript file to keep the clutter down in my primary javascript file.  How can I do this so that the code in the main javascript file will still have access to the objects that I am creating in the auxiliary file?

Comment: one file that has all your objects definition and the other makes use of them. so you add 2 script files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare the objects outside the scope of a method and they will be accessible globally.

**Auxiliary Script:**

```
object myObj;
object myObj;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Do your manipulations here if needed.
});
```

**Primary Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myObj.property = "value";
});
```

Also, reference your "auxiliary" file before your primary one in your markup page like so:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="js/auxiliary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/primary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the help.  Simple question, but I am a newbie to programming

Answer (score 0):

Here's basically what I do (this may not work out of the box, but it's pretty close to how it actually works for me):

1) Create a JS file with a global scope and declare an object to HOLD all those other objects:

**global.js**

```
var Registry = {};

Registry.object1 = { name: "Jack", age: "30" };
Registry.object2 = { name: "Sharon", age: "28" };
```

2) Create a secondary (auxiliary) that USES those objects:

**people.js**

```
(function() {
    console.log("Hi, "+Registry.object1.name+"! Meet "+Registry.object2.name+"! She's only "+Registry.object2.age+" years old!"); 
});
```

which should output: `Hi, Jack! Meet Sharon! She's only 28 years old!`

You would include `global.js` on every page, which contains every global object, and then only use the auxiliary JS files when you need them.

The main reason why I created the Registry object to hold the others is to make sure that no other objects anywhere else can conflict. If I have another object named "object1" somewhere else, you could have some problems, but if you stick them inside another holder object, it makes sure that there aren't any conflicts. (i.e., `Registry.object1` is different from `object1`)

It's useful to note that objects can contain functions (which effectively makes them classes), so you can have global classes to use.

That's basically how I do it. Hope that helps.

Good luck! :)